# Android NullPointerException When retriving Spinner text

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the selected item of a spinner and convert it into a string then save it as a `.txt` file then send, everything works fine until I implemented the spinner and now I'm getting a null pointer exception when I selected No and nothing happens when I select Yes. The Lines referenced in the Logcat are the methods being excecuted in `Updater()`, and the `clickedUpdate` is the the `Updater()` method being run.I'm 100% sure the error occurs in the Updater() Method.

The Updater() Method

```
public String Updater()
{
    Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    TextView dLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLong);
    TextView dLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    EditText xxxxxx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.POinput);
    EditText xxxxxx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.splitPOinput);
    Spinner xxxxxchoice = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.optionselecti);
    String xxxxxx = xxxxxx.getText().toString();
    String dataLat = dLat.getText().toString();
    String dataLong = dLong.getText().toString();
    String xxxxxx = xxxxxx.getText().toString();
    String Update = null;
    TelephonyManager telephonemanager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String PhoneNumber = telephonemanager.getLine1Number();
    String xxxxxxChoicei = xxxxxxchoice.getSelectedItem().toString();
    int choice = 0;
    boolean Choice;
    if(xxxxxxChoicei.equals("Yes"))
    {
        choice = 1;//virtual number used to indicate spinner choice on data server
        Choice = true; //for if statment below
        vibrate.vibrate(100);
    }
    else if (xxxxxxChoicei.equals("No"))
    {
        choice = 0;
        Choice = false;
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Temperature");
    alert.setMessage("Input Temperature");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Check-In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            temperature = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    if(Choice = false)
    {
        alert.show();
    }
    if(xxxxxxxxxChoicei.equals("No"))
    {
        temperature = "DRY";
    }
    String DataIn = PhoneNumber + "," + dataLong + "," + dataLat+","+dataPO+","+splitpo+","+temperature+","+choice;
    try {
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new
                File(getFilesDir() + File.separator + "xxxxxxx_LOCATION_DATA.txt")));
        bufferedWriter.write(DataIn);
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DATAOUT();
    while((!(temperature.equals(""))&& temperature!=null) || xxxxxxxChoicei.equals("No"))
    {
     sendMail("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "DataTest", DATAOUT());
      Update = "Updated";
      deleteFile("xxxxxxx_LOCATION_DATA.txt");
    }
```

logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.checkAscii(MimeUtility.java:1346)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:1069)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1493)
            at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.setText(MimeMessage.java:1477)
            at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.Locator.createMessage(Locator.java:134)
            at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.Locator.sendMail(Locator.java:170)
            at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.Locator.Updater(Locator.java:256)
            at com.example.adrian.trucktracker.Locator.clickedUpdate(Locator.java:264)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3860)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4480)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18686)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: You are crashing in `createMessage()`, presumably due to `DATAOUT()` returning `null`. We cannot help you with any of that, as we do not have the source code to those methods. Also, please note that you appear to be doing disk I/O (and, eventually, network I/O) on the main application thread. Not only is that bad for performance, but your network I/O will crash with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` when you do eventually try to send the email.

Comment: Why are you masking everything with "xxxxxxx"? Makes everything very confusing.

Comment: i've fixed it so that DATAOUT() no longer returns null but now whenever either option is selected no code is excecuted @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0):

So after fixing it so that DATAOUT() no longer returned null (by setting the default string value to `String Dataout = "";`) I got a bunch of errors caused by this statement:

`while((!(temperature.equals(""))&& temperature!=null) || xxxxxxxChoicei.equals("No"))
    {
     sendMail("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "DataTest", DATAOUT());
      Update = "Updated";
      deleteFile("xxxxxxx_LOCATION_DATA.txt");
    }`

which caused an infinite loop, so i fixed that by no longer using the while, however does someone know how to include the while loop without causing my application to crash?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your while loop? Without knowing that, all I can say is for the loop to ever exit once it starts looping you need to change the value of one of the variables  used in the condition (i.e. either temperature or xxxxxxxChoicei). Also, your check of `temperature != null` should be before `!(temperature.equals(""))` or you'll get a null pointer exception if temperature is null. However, I'd instead rewrite the while clause as `while (!"".equals(temperature) || "No".equals(xxxxxxxChoicei))` as then you don't need the check for null anyway.

Comment: @flightplanner in my while loop im sending an email then deleting the file

Comment: Yes, but why do you want a loop? Why not an `if` statement?  Unless you want to sent the email then delete the file multiple times until something happens?

Comment: @flightplanner changing the syntax of the loop still made it infinite

Comment: Well, of course it will if you don't also do what I first said about changing the value of temperature or xxxxxxxChoicei within the loop.